# Variable not assigning from the first try

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

I am having issue with assigning value to global variable. When I click button to console my varible it is empty and when I click button second time, I can see my variable value. I do not know why it is empty at first click and not empty at second click. I want to use variable (this.mc) to define my path in firebase. Look at my code below.
Thanks!

```html
export class LoadsService {

  comp = '';
  dil = '';
  mc = '';
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private auth: AuthService) { 
   }
  

   getUsers() {
    return this.auth.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => {
        //  user['company'];
        this.comp = user['company'];
        return user['company'];
      })
    )
   }
  
   getMc(){
     return this.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
       this.comp = user;
       console.log('Hello', this.comp)
       return this.comp;
      });
    }
    
    getComp(){
      this.comp = this.dil;
      if(this.dil.length <= 0){
        return this.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
          this.comp = user;
          console.log('Bye', this.comp)
          return this.comp;
         });
      }
      else{
        console.log('Bye1', this.dil)
      }
    }

  async addLoad(load){
   load.creator = auth().currentUser.uid;
    return this.db.collection(`companies/${this.mc}/currentLoads`).add(load).then(ref => {
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where are u calling oneMore() ?

Comment: @pc_coder I am calling oneMore() at check() and I am calling getComp and getMc at same place. And check() works when I click button

Comment: If you are doing both three at the same time you can't get value due to async . while you console it, mc may still waiting response from request.

Comment: @pc_coder So what will be solution? I just do not want other button :\

Comment: place the full code. We don't know where and how you call listed methods.

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehrvarzi this is full code